# Migrating to Gradle Plugin 3.0

Tags: android, gradle

I am migrating our project to the Gradle 3.0 plugin, I am going error by error a I am new in Gradle.

Now, I am facing this issue:

```
Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task ':ComponentsLib:mergeProdReleaseResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':ComponentsLib:prodReleaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :Datastore.
     Required by:
         project :ComponentsLib
      > Project :ComponentsLib declares a dependency from configuration 'releaseCompile' to configuration 'prodRelease' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :Datastore.
```

Here is the gradle.build for ComponentLib module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
flavorDimensions "default"
publishNonDefault true

compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}

productFlavors {
    internal {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.debugMinSdkVersion
    }
    prod {
    }
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}

lintOptions {
    quiet false
    warningsAsErrors true
    abortOnError true
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    textReport = true
    htmlReport = false
    xmlReport = false
    ignore(rootProject.ext.lintIgnore as String[])
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    debugCompile project(path: ':Datastore', configuration: 'internalDebug')
    releaseCompile project(path: ':Datastore', configuration: 'prodRelease')
}
```

And here is the gradle.build for Datastore module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
flavorDimensions "default"
publishNonDefault true

compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}

productFlavors {
    internal {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.debugMinSdkVersion
    }
    prod {
    }
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}

lintOptions {
    quiet false
    warningsAsErrors true
    abortOnError true
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    textReport = true
    htmlReport = false
    xmlReport = false
    ignore(rootProject.ext.lintIgnore as String[])
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    debugCompile project(path: ':Core', configuration: 'internalDebug')
    releaseCompile project(path: ':Core', configuration: 'prodRelease')
}
```

The modules are build in order -> ':Core', ':Datastore', ':ComponentsLib', ':Push',....

Any idea what is happening here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it.
Porblem was that I had to rewrite

```
 debugCompile project(path: ':Datastore', configuration: 'internalDebug')
releaseCompile project(path: ':Datastore', configuration: 'prodRelease')
```

to

```
instalation project(':Datastore')
```

because the new Gradle 3.0 plugin manages build process in the different way.